# how to change direction when i go up a ladder and create a win function

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a code for when I go up a ladder it will change directions so far i have got it working for when I land on snakes and go down it changes direction but when i go up a ladder it goes the wrong way I'm also wondering how I can make a function where when it I roll a die and it lands on 100 i get win but if it rolls and goes more than 100 it goes back to previous spot here's the code so far

```
namespace JokosenumiAkeem

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    const int START_ROW = 11;
    const int START_COL = 1;
    const int WIN_ROW = 1;
    const int WIN_COL = 1;
    const int EDGE_RIGHT = 10;
    const int EDGE_LEFT = 1;
    const int NUMBER_OF_SNAKES = 8;
    const int NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS = 3;
    const int NUMBER_OF_LADDERS = 8;

    Random _random;
    int _diceRoll;
    int _currentPlayer;
    int _currentEdgeCol;
    int _IsMovingLR;

    // use an array to store the variables for playing for each player separately
    // what do I need to store for each player
    // _IsMovingLR, _currentEdgeCol, 
    // int[2] { 1, EDGE_RIGHT }
    // int[2] { 1, EDGE_RIGHT }
    // int[2] { 1, EDGE_RIGHT }
    int[][] _Players;
    int[][] _Ladders;
    int[][] _Snakes;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupSnakes();
        SetUpLadders();
        SetupPlayers();
        // set up my game variables.
        _currentPlayer = 1;
        // from the player array, get the values
        _IsMovingLR = _Players[_currentPlayer - 1][0];
        _currentEdgeCol = _Players[_currentPlayer - 1][1];
        _random = new Random();
    }

    private void SetUpLadders()
    {
        _Ladders = new int[NUMBER_OF_LADDERS][]{
                                              new int[4] {3, 1, 1, 2},
                                              new int[4] {3, 9, 1, 10 },
                                              new int[4] {5, 10, 4, 7},
                                              new int[4] {8, 8, 2, 4 },
                                              new int[4] {8, 1, 5, 2 },
                                              new int[4] {10, 1, 7, 3 },
                                              new int[4] {10, 4, 9, 7 },
                                              new int[4] {10, 9, 7, 10 },
        };
    }

    private void SetupPlayers()
    {

        _Players = new int[NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS][]
        {
            // stores {_IsMovingLR, _currentEdgeCol }
            new int[2] { 1, EDGE_RIGHT },
            new int[2] { 1, EDGE_RIGHT },
            new int[2] { 1, EDGE_RIGHT }
        };
    }

    private void SetupSnakes()
    {
        // initialise the global variable for snakes here
        // this adds a single dimensional (simple) array for each snake.
        // Each snake is represented as int[4] { TopRow, TopCol, BottomRow, BottomCol }
        _Snakes = new int[NUMBER_OF_SNAKES][] {
                                                new int[4] {9, 4, 10, 7 },
                                                new int[4] {5, 7, 7, 7 },
                                                new int[4] {4, 2, 9, 2},
                                                new int[4] {4, 4, 5, 1 },
                                                new int[4] {2, 7, 7, 5 },
                                                new int[4] {1, 3, 3, 2 },
                                                new int[4] {1, 6, 3, 6 },
                                                new int[4] {1, 8, 3, 8}

        };
    }
    private async void btnDiceRoll_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // generate random number
        //_diceRoll = 4;
        _diceRoll = _random.Next(1, 7);
        // update the dice roll label
        lblDiceRoll.Text = _diceRoll.ToString();
        lblUpdates.Text = "P " + _currentPlayer;
        // move piece
        await MovePiece();

        // get the next player.
        _currentPlayer++;
        if (_currentPlayer == 4) { _currentPlayer = 1; }
        // from the player array, get the values
        _IsMovingLR = _Players[_currentPlayer - 1][0];
        _currentEdgeCol = _Players[_currentPlayer - 1][1];

    }

    #region PIECE MOVEMENT CODE
    private async Task MovePiece()  // async marks the MovePiece method as using an await call
    {
        // if it's the first move, put the row = 10
        // which piece am I moving - x:Name="bvP1"
        // FindByName - looks for x:Name properties in XAML
        string currPlayer = "bvP" + _currentPlayer.ToString();
        BoxView bvPlayer = (BoxView)GrdBoard.FindByName(currPlayer);
        int currPlayerCol = (int)bvPlayer.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);

        // is this the first move.
        if (START_ROW == (int)bvPlayer.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty))
        {
            bvPlayer.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, START_ROW - 1);
            bvPlayer.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, START_COL);
            _diceRoll--;
            await MoveHorizontal(bvPlayer, _diceRoll);
            // CheckForLadders();
            return;
        }

        // if I get to here, then it's a later move
        // if edgeCol - player Col <= dice roll, then simple move from L -> R
        //if( _diceRoll <= Math.Abs(_currentEdgeCol - currPlayerCol) )
        if (_diceRoll <= Math.Abs(_currentEdgeCol - currPlayerCol))
        {
            // translate my player piece
            await MoveHorizontal(bvPlayer, _diceRoll);
        }
        else // move around a corner
        {
            // Left to Right movement of diff
            int diff = Math.Abs(_currentEdgeCol - currPlayerCol);
            await MoveHorizontal(bvPlayer, diff);
            _diceRoll -= diff;  // decrement diceroll by diff

            // move vertically
            await MoveVerticalOneRow(bvPlayer);
            _diceRoll--;

            // move R-L with what's left on the dice roll (subtract columns)
            await MoveHorizontal(bvPlayer, _diceRoll);
        }


        CheckForSnakes(bvPlayer);
        if( WIN_ROW ==(int)bvPlayer.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty))
        {
            CheckForWin(bvPlayer);
        }
        CheckForLadders(bvPlayer);
    }

    private void CheckForLadders(BoxView player)
    {
        int iCount = 0;
        int indexRTop = 0, indexCTop = 1;
        int indexRBottom = 2, indexCBottom = 3;
        int playerRow, playerCol;
        int deltaRows = 1;

        playerRow = (int)player.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        playerCol = (int)player.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);

        while (iCount < NUMBER_OF_LADDERS)
        {
            if((playerRow == _Ladders[iCount][indexRTop]) &&
               (playerCol == _Ladders[iCount][indexCTop]))
            {
                lblUpdates.Text = "You landed on a ladder";
                // if true the player will move to the top of the ladder
                player.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, _Ladders[iCount][indexRBottom]);
                player.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, _Ladders[iCount][indexCBottom]);
                deltaRows = _Ladders[iCount][indexRBottom] + _Ladders[iCount][indexRBottom];
            }
            iCount++;
        }
        // if move down an odd number of rows, change direction
        if (deltaRows % 2 == 1)
        {
            ChangeUp();
        }
    }

    private async Task MoveHorizontal(BoxView bvPlayer, int numSpaces)
    {
        int horizontalDistance = ((int)GrdBoard.Width / 12) * numSpaces * _IsMovingLR;
        uint timeValue = (uint)(Math.Abs(numSpaces) * 150);
        int currPlayerCol = (int)bvPlayer.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);

        await bvPlayer.TranslateTo(horizontalDistance, 0, timeValue);   // takes time, so ask the system to wait for it to finish
        bvPlayer.TranslationX = 0;
        // set the Col to the curr + dice roll
        bvPlayer.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, currPlayerCol + (numSpaces * _IsMovingLR));
        ChangeUp();
    }

    private async Task MoveVerticalOneRow(BoxView pieceToMove)
    {
        int verticalDistance = (int)GrdBoard.Width / 12;    // 1 square
        uint timeValue = (uint)150;
        await pieceToMove.TranslateTo(0, -1 * verticalDistance, timeValue);   // takes time, so ask the system to wait for it to finish
        pieceToMove.TranslationY = 0;
        pieceToMove.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, (int)pieceToMove.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty) - 1);

        ChangeDirection();
    }

    private void ChangeUp()
    {
        _IsMovingLR *= +1;
        //                       if LR = -1
        //                          1           10
        _currentEdgeCol = Math.Max(EDGE_LEFT, EDGE_RIGHT * _IsMovingLR);
        // update the player array
        _Players[_currentPlayer + 1][0] = _IsMovingLR;
        _Players[_currentPlayer + 1][1] = _currentEdgeCol;
    }

    private void ChangeDirection()
    {
        _IsMovingLR *= -1;
        //                       if LR = -1
        //                          1           10
        _currentEdgeCol = Math.Max(EDGE_LEFT, EDGE_RIGHT * _IsMovingLR);
        // update the player array
        _Players[_currentPlayer - 1][0] = _IsMovingLR;
        _Players[_currentPlayer - 1][1] = _currentEdgeCol;
    }
    #endregion

    #region CHECK FOR SNAKES, LADDERS, WIN CONDITION
    /// <summary>
    /// checks if the player position is currently the head of a snake.
    /// </summary>
    private void CheckForSnakes(BoxView player)
    {
        int iCounter = 0;
        int indexRTop = 0, indexCTop = 1;
        int indexRBottom = 2, indexCBottom = 3;
        int playerRow, playerCol;
        int deltaRows = 0;

        playerRow = (int)player.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        playerCol = (int)player.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);

        // loop through the array of snakes to check if the Row and Col are equal

        while (iCounter < NUMBER_OF_SNAKES)
        {
            // playerRow == _Snakes[iCounter][indexRTop]
            if ((playerRow == _Snakes[iCounter][indexRTop]) &&
                (playerCol == _Snakes[iCounter][indexCTop]))
            {
                // at the top of a snake.-
                lblUpdates.Text = "You landed on a snake.";
                // if true - then player is moved back to the bottom of the snake.
                player.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, _Snakes[iCounter][indexRBottom]);
                player.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, _Snakes[iCounter][indexCBottom]);
                deltaRows = _Snakes[iCounter][indexRBottom] - _Snakes[iCounter][indexRTop];
            }
            iCounter++;
        }
        // if move down an odd number of rows, change direction
        if (deltaRows % 2 == 1)
        {
            ChangeDirection();
        }
        
    }

    private void CheckForWin(BoxView player)
    {
        // if the player is on row 1 -Winning Row
        // if the player is within dice roll of col 1 - winning col
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Hang Tight - working code coming up.

Comment: Can you please make it clearer that which part of code need help? The code you post in unable to run and it's a bit difficult for us to understand as it is very long.

Comment: @jack hua I need help in the private void checkforLadder and CheckForWin

Comment: Can you please also share me the code in xaml so that I can test it on my side?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of self playing - console Snakes & Ladders

```
class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     // Can create many new boards. This example is 2 players, 5 snakes and 2 ladders.
     var game = new SnakesAndLadders(2, 5, 2);
     game.PrintBoard();

     while (!game.IsFinished)
     {
        game.Play();
        game.PrintPlayers();
     }

     Console.WriteLine($"{game.WinnerName} - Won");
     Console.ReadLine();
  }
}

enum PropType
{
  Snake = 0,
  Ladder = 1
}

class SnakesAndLadders
{
  const int START = 1;
  const int END = 100;
  private Dictionary<int, Prop> _Props = new Dictionary<int, Prop>();
  private List<Player> _Players;
  private readonly Random _Randomizer = new Random();
  private Player _CurrentPlayer;
  public bool IsFinished { get; private set; }

  public string WinnerName
  {
     get => IsFinished ? _CurrentPlayer.Name : string.Empty;
  }

  public SnakesAndLadders(int players, int snakes, int ladders)
  {
     SetupPlayers(players);
     SetupSnakes(snakes);
     SetupLadders(ladders);
  }

  private void SetupPlayers(int playerCount)
  {
     _Players = new List<Player>(playerCount);

     for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
        _Players.Add(new Player(i + 1, $"Player{i + 1}", 1));

     for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
        _Players[i].Next = _Players[(i + 1) % playerCount];

     _CurrentPlayer = _Players.FirstOrDefault();
  }

  private void SetupSnakes(int snakeCount)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < snakeCount;)
     {
        int start = _Randomizer.Next(100);
        int end = _Randomizer.Next(100);

        if (start < end || start == END || start == START)
           continue;

        if (_Props.TryGetValue(start, out var prop) == false)
        {
           _Props.Add(start, new Prop(PropType.Snake, start, end));
           i++;
        }
     }
  }

  private void SetupLadders(int ladderCount)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < ladderCount;)
     {
        int start = _Randomizer.Next(100);
        int end = _Randomizer.Next(100);

        if (start > end || start == START)
           continue;

        if (_Props.TryGetValue(start, out var prop) == false)
        {
           _Props.Add(start, new Prop(PropType.Ladder, start, end));
           i++;
        }
     }
  }

  private int RollDice()
  {
     int chance = 0;
     int newMove = 0;
     do
     {
        chance = _Randomizer.Next(1, 7);
        Console.Write($"Dice Rolled: {chance} ");
        newMove += chance;
     } while (chance == 6);

     Console.WriteLine();
     return newMove < END ? newMove : END;
  }

  private int GetNewSpot(int spot, int move, string playerName)
  {
     if (_Props.TryGetValue(spot + move, out var prop))
     {
        Console.WriteLine($"{playerName} - {(prop.Type == PropType.Snake ? "Snake Bites" : "Climbs Ladder")}");
        return prop.End;
     }
     else
        return spot + move;
  }

  public void Play()
  {
     if (!IsFinished && _CurrentPlayer != null)
     {
        Console.Write($"{_CurrentPlayer.Name} - ");
        int moveValue = RollDice();
        // Check for Props
        moveValue = GetNewSpot(_CurrentPlayer.Spot, moveValue, _CurrentPlayer.Name);

        if (moveValue < END)
           _CurrentPlayer.Move(moveValue);
        else if (moveValue == END)
        {
           // Game Over Player Won
           _CurrentPlayer.Move(moveValue);
           IsFinished = true;
           return;
        }

        _CurrentPlayer = _CurrentPlayer.Next;
     }
  }

  public void PrintBoard()
  {
     var snakes = _Props.Values.Where(p => p.Type == PropType.Snake).ToList();
     Console.WriteLine($"Snakes[{snakes.Count}]: {string.Join(", ", snakes.Select(s => $"{s.Start}->{s.End}"))}");
     var ladders = _Props.Values.Where(p => p.Type == PropType.Ladder).ToList();
     Console.WriteLine($"Ladders[{ladders.Count}]: {string.Join(", ", ladders.Select(s => $"{s.Start}->{s.End}"))}");
  }

  public void PrintPlayers()
  {
     foreach (var player in _Players)
        Console.WriteLine($"{player.Id}-{player.Name} - At:{player.Spot}");
  }
}

class Prop
{
  public PropType Type { get; private set; }
  public int Start { get; private set; }
  public int End { get; private set; }

  public Prop(PropType pType, int start, int end)
  {
     Type = pType;
     Start = start;
     End = end;
  }
}

class Player
{
  public int Id { get; private set; }
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public int Spot { get; private set; }
  public Player Next { get; set; }

  public Player(int id, string name, int spot)
  {
     Id = id;
     Name = name;
     Spot = spot;
  }

  public void Move(int newSpot)
  {
     Spot = newSpot;
  }
}
```